# Alternative to ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING with sequence object

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query in PostgreSQL 9.5 but I need to translate it to not use `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`:

```
INSERT INTO grade(id, name, group_id) 
SELECT nextval('hibernate_sequence') as id, name, ? 
FROM grade 
WHERE group_id = ?
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

Where only the **id** has UNIQUE constraint

I have been reading the similar questions and I understand that with LOCKS and WHERE NOT EXISTS this can be done. But I'm struggling on how to achieve this with the hibernate_sequence, to check if for the value given by `nextval('hibernate_sequence')` is already on the table.

If I try this, the second call to `nextval` will be returning a different value than the first right? even if is in the same query?

```
INSERT INTO grade(id, name, group_id) 
SELECT nextval('hibernate_sequence') as id, name, ? 
FROM grade 
WHERE group_id = ? AND
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM grade g1 WHERE g1.id = nextval('hibernate_sequence'))
```

And if I use `currval`, it ensures that will be returning the one getting on the SELECT or it could be other(if two queries run `nextval` at the same time).

Anything I could read to understand this?

Comment: I think that you can apply some kind of (`BEFORE`) trigger (will return `NULL` or `NEW`) here if you want to avoid `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`

Comment: Since `hibernate_sequence` is a sequence there is no need to check if it exists. Providing **all IDs** on that table have been assigned using it, Postgres guarantees it is unique. From the [Sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-sequence.html) Documentation  *once a value has been fetched (from a sequence) it is considered used and will not be returned again*.